# batch ftp script with DATE command not working

Tags: windows, date, permissions, batch-file, cmd

I am uploading a running a simple batch script which downloads a file from one server and uploads it to another.  The file name is based on the previous day ie. 20111124.zip (YYYYMMDD). The script works fine on all the boxes I have tried it on, however when it is run on a colleagues windows 7 box it fails.  The DATE command returns a zero.  I have already tried setting the UAC to off but that did not resolve the issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SETLOCAL
SET dwMONTH=%DATE:~4,2%
SET /A dwDAY=%DATE:~7,2%-1
IF %dwDAY% LSS 10 (SET dwDay=0%dwDay%)
SET dwYEAR=%DATE:~10,4%
SET dwDate=%dwYEAR%-%dwMONTH%-%dwDAY%
SET mydate=%dwYEAR%%dwMONTH%%dwDAY%
echo %mydate%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 doesnt include a day name,
e.g. on windows XP %date% contains "Di 25.10.2011" (im on a german computer system)
and Win7 only "25.10.2011",
so your offset (7) is pointing to the wrong spot